Show assigned product categories in WooCommerce product title
I need to show all associated product categories within the single product title. For example, selling a split-release record, which has two different artists categories associated.
Per this answer, the below code will display a single product category term within the product title.
function category_single_product(){

    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
    
    foreach ($terms as $term) ?>
    
        <b><span itemprop="name" class="product_category_title"><span><?php echo $term->name; ?></span></span></b>

<?php }

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'category_single_product', 25 );

But it's not showing all associated product categories within the single product title.  How can I display the multiple category terms?

To display all product categories associated to a product (at the end of the product title), try the following:
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'category_single_product', 20 );
function category_single_product(){
    // Get product category terms for the current product
    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

    // Check if there are product categories assigned to the product
    if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
        // Get only an array of term names
        $term_names = array_column( $terms, 'name' ); 

        // Output the comma separated string of term names
        printf('<b><span itemprop="name" class="product_category_title"><span>%s</span></span></b>', implode(', ', $term_names) );
    }
}

It should work

Perfect - thank you! How can I move the categories to the end of the product title?
